# What's better jsonb array of objects, jsonb objects or rows without a unique index for materialized view?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, materialized-views

This is the result of a query that counts stock transfers between multiple warehouses, and ultimately gives out the breakdown of stock per warehouse.

I want to store this in a materialized view, however the result wont have a unique index.

**I'm not sure if this is a big deal or not?**

**Will indexing multiple of the same offer the same level of performance as as a unique index?**

For example:

| prod_article_pvt_uuid | whse_whs_pvt_uuid | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d9922868-163b-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8 | 0 |
| d9922868-163b-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8 | 3 |
| d9922868-163b-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8 | 2 |
| ff31fe88-1639-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8 | 2 |
| ff31fe88-1639-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8 | 4 |
| ff31fe88-1639-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8 | 1 |

VS

With primary key `jsonb` array of objects:

| prod_article_pvt_uuid | quantity | breakdown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d9922868-163b-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 5 | [{"quantity": 0.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8"}, {"quantity": 3.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8"}, {"quantity": 2.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8"}] |
| ff31fe88-1639-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 7 | [{"quantity": 2.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8"}, {"quantity": 4.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8"}, {"quantity": 1.000000, "whse_whs_pvt_uuid": "e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8"}] |

Or just `jsonb` objects:

| prod_article_pvt_uuid | quantity | breakdown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d9922868-163b-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 5 | {"60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8": 0.000000, "d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8": 3.000000, "e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8": 2.000000} |
| ff31fe88-1639-11ec-b96d-784f436cb4ef | 7 | {"60df78de-44ab-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8": 2.000000, "d8946d90-44aa-11ea-909d-000c29a3d8c8": 4.000000, "e541054e-44a5-11ea-8cde-000c29a3d8c8": 1.000000} |

Comment: Isn't prod_article_pvt_uuid, whse_whs_pvt_uuid unique? Looks like it is.

Comment: If in doubt, start with a properly normalized data model. So that would be solution 1 (and make sure the UUID columns are defined with the data type `uuid`!)

Comment: @CetinBasoz the results of the query that counts the stock returns the quantity of a product per warehouse. So that means duplicates of the warehouses and product ids. Like the first example.

Comment: I don't see a duplication, nor a duplication makes sense. What I see is  (prod_article_pvt_uuid, whse_whs_pvt_uuid) is unique. IOW it is plain unique key.

Comment: @CetinBasoz You mean a combined index of both article and warehouse?

Comment: Yes it shouts out as being unique. This looks like a summary like (ProductId,WareHouseId).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Interesting.... Will I be able to take advantage of the index when I just query the product_id? Or should I add an additional non-unique index on product_id just for itself? Cause in most cases I'll be querying only the product_id. But in order to refresh the materialized view I need a unique index...

Comment: @Nikk, you can put the product_id in front to take advantage of it whichever it is (likely prod_article_pvt_uuid, field names are rather cryptic but it should be that). Index entries would be like Product1, Wh1 ProductId1, Wh2 ...